# JavaFX 8 Progress Bar Update from Calculation Script Class

Tags: progress-bar, javafx-8, essbase

I am having a hell of a time trying to get this progress bar in JavaFX 8 to work.  I know I probably should be using a Task to Update Progress but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I removed the server API specific code and just kept the GUI, Call, and 1 Calc Class for simplicity.

The goal is to:

1. Recognize which calc is being called from the choicebox
2. Set the variables to monitor the progress of the calculation iterations
3. Get the `progressbar` to update with the progress from the Calculation Script Classes.

Here is my code:

**UI Main Class**

```
package javafxessbasecalcscriptapp;

import com.essbase.api.base.EssException;
import com.essbase.api.datasource.IEssOlapServer;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import static javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.Connect.getEss;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.Connect.getOLAPSvr;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.ForecastCalcs.getFCalcProg;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.SupplementalCalcs.getCalcSProg;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.WrapperCalcs.getCalcWProg;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.ForecastCalcs.getForecastList;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.SupplementalCalcs.getSupplementalList;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.WrapperCalcs.getWrapperList;

public class JavafxEssbaseCalcScriptApp extends Application {
Button btnRunCalc = new Button();
ChoiceBox mainChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
ProgressBar mainProgBar = new ProgressBar(0);
public Double calcProg = 0.0;
public Double calcListSize = 0.0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    new SecondStage();
}


    public class SecondStage extends Stage {

            ChoiceBox mainChoiceBox = mainChoiceBox();
            mainChoiceBox.setDisable(false);
            mainChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String oldCalc, String newCalc) {
                    if (oldCalc != null) {
                        switch(oldCalc) {
                            case "Forecast": System.out.println("Clear Forecast"); setCalcScript(null); calcProg = getFCalcProg(); calcListSize = (double) getForecastList().size() /*select forecast calc scripts*/; break;
                            case "Wrapper": System.out.println("Clear Wrapper"); setCalcScript(null); calcProg = getCalcWProg(); calcListSize = (double) getWrapperList().size()/*select wrapper calc scripts*/; break;
                            case "Supplemental": System.out.println("Clear Supplemental"); setCalcScript(null); calcProg = getCalcSProg(); ; calcListSize = (double) getSupplementalList().size()/*select supplemental calc scripts*/; break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (newCalc != null) {
                        switch(newCalc) {
                            case "Forecast": System.out.println("Load Forecast"); setCalcScript("Forecast") /*select forecast calc scripts*/; break;
                            case "Wrapper": System.out.println("Load Wrapper"); setCalcScript("Wrapper") /*select wrapper calc scripts*/; break;
                            case "Supplemental": System.out.println("Load Supplemental"); setCalcScript("Supplemental") /*select supplemental calc scripts*/; break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            ProgressBar mainProgBar = mainProgBar();
            mainProgBar.setProgress(calcProg);

            try {
                btnRunCalc = btnRunCalc();
            } catch (EssException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavafxEssbaseCalcScriptApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            btnRunCalc.setDisable(false);
            btnRunCalc.setOnAction((ActionEvent revent) -> {
                System.out.println("Calc Running");
                //Run Calc Script                
                RunCalcs.main(args);
                Task t = new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        double i = calcProg;
                        double maximum = calcListSize;
                        for (i < maximum; i++) {
                            // Here you update the progress each time
                            updateProgress(i, maximum);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            });

            final Pane rootMain = new Pane();
                rootMain.getChildren().add(btnRunCalc);
                rootMain.getChildren().add(mainChoiceBox);
                rootMain.getChildren().add(mainProgBar);
                rootMain.getChildren().add(btnCancelCalc);

            Scene sceneMain = new Scene(rootMain, 330, 320, Color.WHITE);
            this.setTitle("Essbase Calc Script Application");
            this.setScene(sceneMain);
            this.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
            this.show();
        }
    }

    public ChoiceBox mainChoiceBox() {
        mainChoiceBox.setPrefSize(230, 25);
        mainChoiceBox.setItems(observableArrayList("Forecast", "Wrapper", "Supplemental"));
        mainChoiceBox.setLayoutX(50);
        mainChoiceBox.setLayoutY(200);
        mainChoiceBox.setRotate(0);
        mainChoiceBox.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        mainChoiceBox.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        return mainChoiceBox;
    }

    public ProgressBar mainProgBar() {
        mainProgBar.setPrefSize(230, 25);
        mainProgBar.setLayoutX(50);
        mainProgBar.setLayoutY(290);
        mainProgBar.setRotate(0);
        mainProgBar.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        mainProgBar.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        return mainProgBar;
    }

    private Button btnRunCalc() throws EssException {
        btnRunCalc.setText("Run Calculations");
        btnRunCalc.setDefaultButton(true);
        btnRunCalc.setPrefSize(100, 25);
        btnRunCalc.setLayoutX(50);
        btnRunCalc.setLayoutY(237);
        btnRunCalc.setRotate(0);
        btnRunCalc.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        btnRunCalc.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        return btnRunCalc;
    }

    public Button btnCancelCalc(Stage secondStage) {
        btnCancelCalc.setText("Close");
        btnCancelCalc.setCancelButton(true);
        btnCancelCalc.setPrefSize(60, 25);
        btnCancelCalc.setLayoutX(220);
        btnCancelCalc.setLayoutY(237);
        btnCancelCalc.setRotate(0);
        btnCancelCalc.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        btnCancelCalc.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        return btnCancelCalc;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static String getCalcScript() {
        return calcScript;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param calcScript
     */
    public static void setCalcScript(String calcScript) {
        JavafxEssbaseCalcScriptApp.calcScript = calcScript;
    }
}
```

**Call Calculation Scripts Class**:

```
package javafxessbasecalcscriptapp;

/**
 *
 * @author jdsmith
 */
public class RunCalcs {

        String[] args = {};    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String calcName = JavafxEssbaseCalcScriptApp.getCalcScript();
        switch (calcName) {
            case "Forecast":
                ForecastCalcs.main(args);
                System.out.println("Forecast Calc Scripts Complete");
                break;
            case "Wrapper":
                WrapperCalcs.main(args);
                System.out.println("Wrapper Calc Scripts Complete");
                break;
            case "Supplemental":
                SupplementalCalcs.main(args);
                System.out.println("Supplemental Calc Scripts Complete");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**1 of the 3 Calculation Script Classes**:

```
package javafxessbasecalcscriptapp;

import com.essbase.api.base.EssException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.Connect.getEss;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.Connect.getEssCube;
import static javafxessbasecalcscriptapp.Connect.getOLAPSvr;

/**
 *
 * @author jdsmith
 */
public class ForecastCalcs {
    private static double calcFProg;
    public static double iF;
    //create list
    public static List<String> forecastList = new ArrayList<String>();
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //add Calc Scripts to list
        Collections.addAll(getForecastList(),"Agg_Act","EAMN_Int","EAOP_NOI"
                  ,"EAOP_RCX","EAOP_CEx","EA_RENet","EA_DProp","IA_RECst"
                  ,"IA_NOI","IA_CNOI","IA_IntEx","IAMN_Cex","IAOP_Cex"
                  ,"IA_DepEx","IA_Debt","UA_RECst","UA_ACR","UA_NOI","UA_CNOI"
                  ,"UA_IntEx","UA_CeX","UA_DepEx","Agg_Fcst","ENT_GA","ENT_Inv"
                  ,"ENT_OFF","ENT_OCF","ENT_PED","ENT_Bnd","ENT_TOS","ENT_AMF"
                  ,"ENT_Dil","ENT_PSQ","ENT_CIP","ENT_TOS","ENT_CI","ENT_TOS"
                  ,"ENT_Div","ENT_TOS","ENT_Drp","ENT_TOS","ENT_CF","Agg_Fcst");


        //Iterate via "while loop"
        System.out.println("\n==> While Loop Iterate Calcs....");
        setiF(0);

        for (String item : getForecastList()) {   
            setFCalcProg(getiF()/getForecastList().size());
            System.out.println(getiF()/getForecastList().size());                                
            System.out.println(getForecastList().get((int) getiF()));
            setiF(getiF() + 1);
            System.out.println(getiF()+1);
         }


    /**
     * @return the iF
     */
    public static double getiF() {
        return iF;
    }

    /**
     * @param aiF the iF to set
     */
    public static void setiF(double aiF) {
        iF = aiF;
    }

    /**
     * @return the forecastList
     */
    public static List<String> getForecastList() {
        return forecastList;
    }

    /**
     * @param aForecastList the forecastList to set
     */
    public static void setForecastList(List<String> aForecastList) {
        forecastList = aForecastList;
    }

    /**
     * @return the calcProg
     */
    public static double getFCalcProg() {
        return calcFProg;
    }

    /**
     * @param aCalcProg the calcProg to set
     */
    public static void setFCalcProg(double aFCalcProg) {
        calcFProg = aFCalcProg;
    }
}
```

I have tried to find solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to fit with my scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Where do you actually execute your `Task`? It looks like some code is missing.

Comment: Hi James, yes, I was attempting to have the task execute when the "Run Calcs" button was pressed but was unable to get it to update the Progressbar.  The task is incomplete.  If I am along the right track, then I would appreciate seeing how the task is completed and linked to the Progressbar.

Comment: You create the task but you never execute it. You need to add something like `Thread thread = new Thread(t); thread.setDaemon(true); thread.start();`.